# Clear Select options when selecting one field while using multiple forms on same page

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I have a situation where the second select list option is generated from the first select list selected option. Like when we select Country corresponding states are generated in next select list.

In my case I am having multiple forms on single page which are same. Can anyone let me know how to implement it on multiple forms.

I tried the following code but it didn't work

```
        $(".country").change(function(){
       $.get("sample.php?val=" + $(this).val(),
        function(data){
            $(this).parent().next().children('.state').children('option').remove();
            $(this).parent().next().children('.state').append(data);
        });
```

Waiting for your support thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the HTML (to tell where the lists are) as well as a sample response from sample.php?

Comment: Thanks every one for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the "multiple forms" all have `<select class='country'>` and `<select class='state'>` contained inside the same `<form>` element you can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to traverse and not be so tied to exact DOM positioning:

```
$('.country').change(function() { 
  var $stateSelect = $(this).closest('form').find('select.state');

  $.get('sample.php?val='+$(this).val(), function(data) {
    $stateSelect.empty().append(data);
  });
});
```

Also, your `$(this)` that you were using inside of the callback probably doesn't work properly.  That callback function gets called with `this` as an AJAX options object for jQuery.  You can use function scoping to save `var $this = $(this);` in the event function (like I saved `$stateSelect`) if you need to keep it around for use inside your other callbacks/closures inside of the event function.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".country").change(function(){
   $.get("sample.php?val=" + $(this).val(),
    function(data){
        // console.log($this);
        $(this).parent().next().children('.state').children('option').remove();
        $(this).parent().next().children('.state').append(data);
    });
```

I'm not 100% sure, but you might be misunderstanding `this` in the `function(data)`. Try running `console.log($this);` in the line I commented out.

Does the following work? `this` is a nasty concept in JavaScript, but it's powerful and worth learning.

```
    $(".country").change(function(){
     var country = $(this);
   $.get("sample.php?val=" + $(this).val(),
    function(data){
        country.parent().next().children('.state').children('option').remove();
        country.parent().next().children('.state').append(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your relationship between elements is right, this should work, a bit more terse:

```
$('.country').change(function() { 
  var sel = $(this).parent().next().children('.state');
  $.get('sample.php?val='+$(this).val(), function(data) {
    sel.html(data);
  });
});
```

The issue is that `this` doesn't refer to what you think it does when the `$.get` comes back, since it's asynchronous, need to store that reference and use it when it returns.